# How can I round order contracts in tradingview

Tags: tradingview-api

I want to truncate the number of decimal places included in the number of contracts which are bought and sold in each order placed.
For example if the indicator signals a buy of 1.5324 contracts can I truncate this number to 1.532 contracts? Is there any code I can include in my pine script so I can do this?
Thank you

```
strategy(title="IN USE  [bch-usdt]  [strat cash <850usd>]  [close <sma 100>]", default_qty_type=strategy.cash,
     default_qty_value=850)

angle(_src) =>
    rad2degree=100/3.14159265359  //pi
    ang=rad2degree*atan((_src[0] - _src[1])/atr(14))
    
ma_slope=angle(sma(close, 100))

longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 1), sma(close, 100))
if (longCondition)
    stop_level = close*0.95
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("TP/SL", "My Long Entry Id", stop=stop_level)
    
shortCondition = crossunder(sma(close, 1), sma(close, 100))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.close("My Long Entry Id")
    
plot(strategy.netprofit)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in function within Pine for this:

```
round(number,precision)
```

cheers, and happy coding

Comment: Thank you. Sorry but where exactly should I place this in my code ?  Could you copy my code and insert where I should use that function and what I should insert as the number and precision. I am pretty much a noob haha. Thank you for your patience

Comment: I have tried this round() function before but I couldn’t figure out where to put it or what to place between the ()

Comment: you would put the number you wish to round in the first bracket slot, and precision is how many decimals you wish to round to. eg.  round(1.5324, 3)

Comment: Ah I see.  But if I always want the contracts to be rounded regardless of the number. Basically in my pine script as part of the strategy, can I have a function whereby all order contracts that are bought or sold are rounded or truncated to three places. 
Sorry if I am not explaining myself correctly. Thank you